# Flipping a distribution on the Y-axis i.e. getting the value for -x instead of x

Tags: distributions

the title says it all:

I want to flip a distribution on the y axis (that is evaluating it for the negative of the input compared to the standard case).

I want to use this to create a composite or spliced distribution with a left fat tail, but the distribution of my choice (Pareto Distribution) is right facing.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Please show the code in Mathematica format (not an image of the code) that you have tried and what difficulties you encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

dist1[k_, a_] = ParetoDistribution[k, a];
```

Use [`TransformedDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html) to obtain the distribution for `-x`

```
ℋ[k_, a_] = TransformedDistribution[-x,
   x \[Distributed] dist1[k, a]];
```

The [`DistributionParameterAssumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributionParameterAssumptions.html) are inherited

```
DistributionParameterAssumptions[ℋ[k, a]]

(* k > 0 && a > 0 *)

PDF[ℋ[k, a], x]

(* Piecewise[{{a*k^a*(-x)^(-1 - a), k + x <= 0}}, 0] *)

Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate@Table[PDF[ℋ[k, a], x],
    {a, Range[2, 0.5, -0.25]}], {x, -7, -3},
  PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[Range[2, 0.5, -0.25],
     LegendLabel -> Style[a, 14, Bold],
     LegendLayout -> {"Column", 2}], {0.25, 0.7}]],
 {{k, 3}, 0.25, 4, 0.25, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

```
\[ScriptCapitalD] = 
  SplicedDistribution[{1, 2}, {-4, 0, ∞}, {ℋ[3, 2], 
    NormalDistribution[2, 3]}];

Integrate[PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD], x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

(* 1 *)

Integrate[PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD], x], {x, -4, Infinity}]

(* 1 *)

Plot[PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD], x], {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you that solved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace x with -x in PDF:

```
Plot[Table[ PDF[ParetoDistribution[3, α], x], {α, {.5, .75, 1.5}}] // Evaluate, {x, 3, 3 + 4}, 
 Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

```
f[k_, α_, x_] := Piecewise[{{k^α (-x)^(-1 - α) α, x <= k}, {0, True}}]
Plot[Table[f[3, α, x], {α, {.5, .75, 1.5}}] //Evaluate, {x, -7, -3}, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Although now I am faced with a different problem:

How to convert this into a Distribution function?

\[ScriptCapitalH] = 
 ProbabilityDistribution[
  Piecewise[{{k^\[Alpha] (-x)^(-1 - \[Alpha]) \[Alpha], x <= k}, {0, 
     True}}], {k, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {a, -\[Infinity], \
\[Infinity]}, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]

\[ScriptCapitalD] = 
  SplicedDistribution[{1, 
    2}, {0, -4, \[Infinity]}, {\[ScriptCapitalH][3, 2], 
    NormalDistribution[2, 3]}];

seems to not work